# How to proceed dry run ("test") for Docusign certification?

Tags: docusignapi

We are integrating the DocusignAPI in our application. In Docusign certification steps, they are telling like before actual certification we need to done "dry run". How to proceed dry run ("test") for Docusign certification ?

Answer (score 0):

When certifying your integration with DocuSign their website says to email the following with any questions regarding Certification:

```
apicertifications@docusign.com
```

http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/certification